# Very new to python, wanted to ask how to make this infinitely repeat using a while statement:

Tags: python

```
number = int(input("Enter a number"))
for table in range (1,13):
    table2=(f"{number} x {table} = {number*table}")
    print(table2)
```

It works but when i tried a while loop myself it only repeated one line of the multiplication, not the whole lot before repeating. e.g.

```
3x12=36
3x12=36
3x12=36
3x12=36   
3x12=36
3x12=36
etc...
```

**EDIT: Basically I want:**

```
number = int(input("Enter a number"))
for table in range (1,13):
    table2=(f"{number} x {table} = {number*table}")
    print(table2)
```

**to repeat infinitely, which should output:**

```
Enter a number6
6 x 0 = 0
6 x 1 = 6
6 x 2 = 12
6 x 3 = 18
6 x 4 = 24
6 x 5 = 30
6 x 6 = 36
6 x 7 = 42
6 x 8 = 48
6 x 9 = 54
6 x 10 = 60
6 x 11 = 66
6 x 12 = 72
6 x 0 = 0
6 x 1 = 6
6 x 2 = 12
6 x 3 = 18
6 x 4 = 24
6 x 5 = 30
6 x 6 = 36
6 x 7 = 42
6 x 8 = 48
6 x 9 = 54
6 x 10 = 60
6 x 11 = 66
6 x 12 = 72
```

**for ever**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to show your code with the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what you actually want to repeat infinitely, and make sure the while is *outside* of that.

Not sure if this is what you want, but if you just want to keep asking for a number, then showing the multiplication table for that number up to 12, I think you want:

```
while(True):
    number = int(input("Enter a number"))
    for table in range (1,13):
        table2=(f"{number} x {table} = {number*table}")
        print(table2)
```

Wait...now your latest edit shows that you want the input not to be included in the while loop (even though your first edit showed you did).

The answer remains the same, think about what you want to get repeated.  If you don't want to repeat the input line, well...

```
number = int(input("Enter a number"))
while(True):
    for table in range (1,13):
        table2=(f"{number} x {table} = {number*table}")
        print(table2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry for the poorly phrased question -  it's my first time on stack overflow.

Comment: No worries.  I couldn't just add a comment on your post, since I *couldn't* comment until I had 50 reputation...which this correct answer now gives me!

Answer (score 0):

In for loop, you specify the range which includes the lower limit and excludes the upper and does operation as you desired. As I did not see your while loop here, I assume you either miss the count or initialization. The following worked for me. You can initialize table = 1 to start from 1.

```
number = int(input("Enter a number"))
table = 0
while (table < 13):
    table2=(f"{number} x {table} = {number*table}")
    print(table2)
    table += 1

print("Good bye, I printed all.")
```